# Popup in a thread

Tags: android, multithreading, popup

I would like to create a popup after a splashscreen.
But A have a crash. I think, because the popup is create in a thread (but terminated).
So crash..

I don't find a good code :(

Code:

```
Thread splashTread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                boolean error = true;
                try {
                    int waited = 0;

                    Parser parser= Parser();
                    error = parser.init();
                    while (waited < _splashTime) {
                        sleep(100);
                        waited += 100;
                    }

                } finally {

                    if(!error){
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                Main.class));
                        finish();
                    }else{
                        createPopup(context);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have much better luck with a `Handler` and a `Runnable` for this type of thing.  The contents of the Runnable will still execute on the main thread even though you are posting from a different thread.  The `Handler` class executes in whatever thread it is created in.

```
Runnable splashRunnable = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
      if(!error){
         StartActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class));
         finish();
      }else createPopup(context);

    }
};

//in your thread
mHandler.postDelayed(splashRunnable, _splashTime);
```

Comment: Instead of creating your own handler, you should just use an `AsyncTask`

Comment: Handler is better for timed events